# Eixo x minuto a minuto

Tags: r

Preciso identificar e quantificar intervalos de tempo maiores que 5 minutos de uma extensa coluna. Coluna "Time". Segue `dput`:

```
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1541062677, 1541062678, 1541062680, 
1541062681, 1541062681, 1541062683, 1541062685, 1541062686, 1541062688, 
1541062688), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), CIDM = 
c(0.12146956236827, 
0.24293912473654, 0.337352282020179, 0.431765439303817, 0.553235001672087, 
0.674704564040357, 0.769117721323995, 0.863530878607634, 0.985000440975904, 
1.10647000334417)), .Names = c("Time", "CIDM"), row.names = 142320:142329, 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Nenhuma ocorrência da coluna `Time` colocada acima possui mais de 5 minutos de diferença das demais. Além disso, a pergunta está aberta demais. Tome, por exemplo, os horários 12:00, 12:06, 12:12, 12:14, 12:19. Qual é a resposta esperada para um caso como este?

Comment: @MarcusNunes As diferenças não chegam sequer aos 5 segundos.

Comment: Com o mesmo jogo de dados como posso fazer para aparecer mmenuto a minuto? Quando ploto todo o jogo de dados aparece de duas em duas horas. Gostaria que aparecesse minuto a minuto no eixo X. plot(CIDM~Time,type="l",data = CI)

Comment: @JúlioAzambuja, edite sua questão para incluir as informações desse último comentário.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro um exemplo com uma linha com tempo maior do que cinco minutos:

```
set.seed(321)
CI <- data.frame(
  Time = as.POSIXct(sort(sample(1541062677:1541063688, 10)), origin = '1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC'),
  CIDM = c(0.12146956236827, 0.24293912473654, 0.337352282020179, 0.431765439303817, 0.553235001672087, 0.674704564040357, 0.769117721323995, 0.863530878607634, 0.985000440975904, 1.10647000334417)
)
```

A classe POSIX é definida como o número de segundos a partir de uma data de referência (1o de janeiro de 1970 por padrão); por isso aparece como números inteiros quando roda dput. Identificar as linhas com intervalo maior do que cinco minutos é simples usando `diff`:

```
> CI[diff(CI$Time) > 5*60, ]
                Time      CIDM
7 2018-11-01 10:05:32 0.7691177
```

Ou seja, o intervalo entre as linhas 7 e 8 tem mais de cinco minutos.

Para um bom controle da exibição de datas e horas em gráficos, o mais prático é usar `ggplot2` e `scales`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(CI, aes(Time, CIDM)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(minor_breaks = date_breaks("5 min"), date_labels = '%M:%S')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]